# Adding Library using composer.json file

Tags: 8, composer

I am porting my module [Background Video](https://www.drupal.org/project/background_video) from D7 to D8. This module is using third party [Library](https://github.com/georgepaterson/jquery-videobackground). As this file is not available on 'packagist.org', it is not working as normal way defined in S3FS module's composer.json file [here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/s3fs/tree/composer.json?h=8.x-3.x).

I also tried this method also:

```
    "repositories": [
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "Jqeury Video Background", //give package name to anything, must be unique
            "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/georgepaterson/jquery-videobackground", //git url
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master" //git branch-name
        }
    }
}],
"require" : {
  "georgepaterson/jquery-videobackground": "dev-master"
}
```

Someone help me to solve this.

Comment: This isn't specific to Drupal so not the right place for this question. The problem is probably simply that you haven't named the package correctly. It should match what you're requiring, so `georgepaterson/jquery-videobackground` instead of "Jqeury Video Background". See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#root-package for full details

Comment: @Clive, I added the package name as 'georgepaterson/jquery-videobackground', but it is still not working.

Comment: Check with the composer docs - what I described works fine for me, but as I said it’s a general composer issue and not Drupal so not something we cover here

Comment: It may have to do with your composer dev / stable settings.  A source definition is a dev version.  Composer will not use it if you are requirings stable versions.  You might set your repo up as a distribution and use the zip file URL for the latest release.